# What is the best way to export iphoto library to a certain folder structure?

Tags: photos.app

I have done a lot of processing to my iphoto library (organizing events, etc) and I want to export my iphoto library to a external hard drive but I want others to see the files so i don't want to just store the iphoto library package.

Is there any ability to export in certain patterns like

```
Photos / [Year] / [EventName] /
```

or something similar to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Couple of possibilities

1. If you have the latest version of iPhoto 11 there's a limited option in the Export dialogue. (File -> Export. Note the 'Subfolder Format' option in the Export dialogue. Remember you actually have to have an Event selected for the option to appear)
2. For earlier versions, or more granularity, Apps like [iPhoto2Disk](http://www.iphototodisk.com) or [PhoShare](http://code.google.com/p/phoshare/) will help you export to a Folder tree matching your Events.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually had this very same issue, and I didn't want to pay for any solutions - so I created a quick free Applescript that does the work for you.

Open the App, point it to your iPhoto Library, tell it where to save the photos, and go get a cup of coffee. Your photos will be copied *(not moved) to the destination folder, completely sorted with Folder names by Event.

I've posted this on my Mac Help Website: http://soniq.org/soniq/15749/iphoto-export-all-events-to-folders

I know it's an older thread, but this really did help me sort my 2000 events into nice clean folders.

Comment: I tried your script but it only exported some events not all of them, giving me an error.
I should probably show you the error right? I will get a screenshot tonight.

Comment: that would be helpful :)

Comment: The link is now on the wayback machine : http://web.archive.org/web/20140107205920/http://soniq.org/macsoftware/15749/iphoto-export-all-events-to-folders ... but the script is not available